# Why am I not getting an infinite limit?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to3^-}\frac{3}{x - 3} - \frac{3}{x} - 9$. Here's what I have tried.

$$
\lim_{x\to3^-}\frac{3}{x - 3} - \frac{3}{x} - 9 \\
\lim_{x\to3^-}\frac{3x}{x(x - 3)} - \frac{3(x-3)}{x(x-3)} - \frac{9x(x-3)}{x(x-3)} \\
\lim_{x\to3^-}\frac{3x - 3x - 9x^2 + 27x}{x(x - 3)} \\
\lim_{x\to3^-}\frac{- 9x^2 + 27x}{x^2 - 3x)} \\
$$

By L' Hopital's Rule,

$$
\lim_{x\to3^-}\frac{-18x + 27}{2x - 3} \\
\lim_{x\to3^-}\frac{-18}{2} \\
-9 \\
$$

However, Wolfram Alpha claims that the limit is infinity:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x+-%3E+3+%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7Bx+-+3%7D+-+%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7Bx%7D+-+9

Why?

Comment: You've missed a +9 in the numerator of your third centred line. An easier approach would be to use limit of the sum equals sum of the limits, which applies in this case.

Comment: Ah thanks, but $\lim_{x\to3^-}\frac{3}{x - 3}$ can't be calculated directly, right?

Comment: Well, in a sense it can. The conventional answer is that the limit is $-\infty$, since the term $\frac{3}{x-3}$ is less than any given large negative number, provided $x$ is suffiently close to but less than 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second step, $3(x-3)=3x-9$, not $3x$. When you restore the missing term, you’ll find that l’Hospital’s rule no longer applies.

Answer (score 1):

You made an algebra mistake; instead of

$$\lim_{x\to3^-}\frac{3x - 3x - 9x^2 + 27x}{x(x - 3)}$$

It is

$$\lim_{x\to3^-}\frac{3x - 3x + 9 - 9x^2 + 27x}{x(x - 3)}$$

So you just forgot a term.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a term $+9$ on the numerator of your fraction. This matters because then the limit is not of the form $\dfrac{0}{0}$ or $\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}$, which is a hypothesis of l'Hôpital's rule.

Answer (score 0):

The numerator and denominator of the fraction will both be divisible by $x-3$ if the limit exists.  You'll have
$$
\lim_{x\to3} \frac{(x-3)(\cdots\cdots\cdots)}{(x-3)(\cdots\cdots)}.
$$
Then cancel the common factor.  After that, you can plug in $3$ for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use WolframAlpha to help you find where the problem occurred?  Your [third line](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x+%2d%3E+3+%283x%2d3x%2d9x%5E2%2B27x%29%2F%28x%28x-3%29%29) already evaluates to -9, so you know the error is not in the rest of your computation.

In fact the plot shows that your third line is identically equal to -9, which hints that you did something to incorrectly cancel out the $3/(x-3)$ and the $3/x$.  I'm being deliberately vague here to highlight the fact that this basic level of information is in your grasp.